# Is there a way to queue a build from a specific changeset in TFS 2015?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild

I'd like to run a build from an older changeset. When I go to the Builds (in VS2015 or in TFS in the browser) and then select "Queue New Build..." I can select a *shelveset* name in the dialog that pops up. However I see no option for selecting a a *changeset*. I thought this was possible in a previous version of VS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve it by specify the changeset info in **Source Version** of queue build dialog such as `C8` which will build changeset 8. More detail explanation please see below screeshot.

***Note: This function is released with TFS2015 update2.*** To use it, you have to [upgrade to Update2](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/tfs2015-update2-vs) or above.

[image]

Comment: If I right-click the build definition what I get is a dialog titled "QUEUE BUILD FOR <build definition>" with the option to specify the "Queue:" and "Shelveset name:" along with an [...] ellipsis button for selecting shelveset. I'm wondering if the server is configured differently in my case...? Running TFS Server 2015.

Comment: ***Note: This function is released with TFS2015 update2.*** To use it, you have to upgrade to Update2or above. For TFS server 2015, no such options at the moment. Build vNext will currently always build the latest version with optional changeset.

Comment: What is the full syntax or where is the documentation for this? It seems `Cxxxxx` is for changeset numbers and `Lxxxx` is for label names, but can you do dates or something else?

Comment: @qJake - the `versionspec` syntax is documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=vsts#use-a-versionspec-argument-to-specify-affected-versions-of-items

One example given is `D2004-03-22`, which specifies "_the codebase as it existed on 3/22/2004 at 00:00 (midnight)_".

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the old XAML-based builds, not "Build vNext", then you should be able to specify a changeset in the "Get Version" property in the advanced section of the "Parameters" tab on the "Queue Build" dialog.

[image: Screenshot]